# Prove that $\|e_n\|_{n\geq1}$ is bounded.

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let $(e_n)_{n\geq1}$ a sequence in $\ell^2$ such that for all $x\in \ell^2$, we have :

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty |\langle x,e_n\rangle|^2<\infty$$

Prove that $||e_n||_{n\geq1}$ is bounded. By Cauchy-Schwarz

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty |\langle x,e_n\rangle|^2 \leq \sum_{n=1}^\infty | x|^2 |e_n|^2\leq \|x\|_{\ell^2}^2\|e_n\|_{\ell^2}^2$$

I'm stuck here. Any help please?

Comment: What is $||e_n||_{n\geq 1}$? Do you mean $||(e_n)_{n\geq 1}||$?

Comment: @Gary yes is  the same  Just a notation

Comment: @Gary Probably not the norm of a sequence of vectors in $\ell^2$ $\lVert(e_n)_{n\geq 1}\rVert$ but the sequence of the norms of those vectors $(\lVert e_n\rVert)_{n\geq 1}$.

Comment: Hint: Use the principle of uniform boundedness.

Comment: $||e_n||_{\ell^2} \forall n\in \mathbb{N*}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $f_n : \ell^2 \to \ell^2$ be given by
$$ f_n (x) = (\langle x, e_1\rangle,\langle x, e_2\rangle, \cdots, \langle x, e_n\rangle, 0,0,\cdots).$$

Since
$$\sup _{n\in \mathbb N} \|f_n (x)\| = \sup_{n\in \mathbb N} \sqrt {\sum_{k=1}^n |\langle x, e_k\rangle|^2} = \sqrt {\sum_{k=1}^\infty|\langle x, e_k\rangle|^2} < \infty,$$

the uniform boundedness principle implies
$$\sup_{n\in \mathbb N} \|f_n\| < \infty.$$

Since

$$\|f_n\| \ge \|f_n (e_n/\|e_n\|)\| = \sqrt {\sum_{k=1}^n |\langle e_k ,e_n\rangle|^2} \ge \|e_n\|, $$

The sequence of norms $\{\|e_n\|\}$ is also uniformly bounded.

Answer (score 1):

One has to prove that $\sum_n |(x,e_n)|^2 <= C$ when $||x|| <=1$ since if this is the case then for $x=e_n/||e_n||$ we get $||e_n||^2 <= C$. If this is not the case then for any k there is $||x_k|| <=1$ such that $$\sum_n |(x_k,e_n)|^2 >k$$ so for some large $n_k$ $$\sum_1^{n_k}|(x_k,e_n)|^2 > k$$ Now, $x_k$ as bounded admit a weakly convergent subsequent. Say the whole $x_k$ converges weakly to $x_0$. Then one can go with limit in the sum on the left to get $$\sum_1^{n_k}|(x_0,e_n)|^2 > k$$ Hence $$\sum_n |(x_0,e_n)|^2 = \infty$$